# Very likely bug in the R raster package intersect function when intersecting 1 polygon with 1 point

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

Through attempting to get an intersect result from a single point and a single polygon I have found what I believe can only be a bug in the R raster package intersect function.

I have 1 polygon and 1 point, and use intersect as follows:

```
intersect(a_point, a_polygon)
```

Where `a_point` contains an id attribute.  This fails with the error:

> Error in j[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

However, if I reverse the arguments and do:

```
intersect(a_polygon, a_point)
```

It works fine, but doesn't return the id from the point shape file as part of the result which I require.  This is expected behaviour, so fine but I need it to work the other way around.

To rule out there being some peculiarity with my polygon or point data, I created a single polygon and single point spatial object and tested the same hypothesis, and the same result occurred as above with these 'raw' objects.

The following is the code for generating these two 'fake' objects for completeness and so that it can be reproduced:

```
test_list_x = list(530124, 530125)  #For when I use 2 points 
test_list_y =  list(176949, 176950) #For when I use 2 points 

data_frame_object = data.frame(530124, 176950)
names(data_frame_object) = c("Longitude", "Latitude")
coordinates(data_frame_object)=~Longitude+Latitude
proj4string(data_frame_object)=CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894") 
fake_point_shape_object=SpatialPointsDataFrame(data_frame_object, data.frame(id=1:length(data_frame_object)))


coords = matrix(  nrow=5,  ncol=2) 
coords[1,1] =  530106.8
coords[1,2] =  176953.3
coords[2,1] = 530127.5
coords[2,2] =  176953.3
coords[3,1] = 530127.5
coords[3,2] =  176933.3
coords[4,1] = 530106.8
coords[4,2] =  176933.3
coords[5,1] = 530106.8
coords[5,2] = 176953.3
my_fake_polygon = Polygon(coords)

polygon_list = list(my_fake_polygon)

polygon_set <- lapply(seq_along(polygon_list), function(i) Polygons(list(polygon_list[[i]]), i  ))

new_polygons <- SpatialPolygons(polygon_set)
new_polygons@proj4string = CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894") 

df <- data.frame("1")
names(df) = "id"

my_fake_polygon <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(new_polygons,df)
```

Now here's the thing, if I create 2 points next to each other (so they are both within the polygon) instead of just one, it works fine, no error.  Suggesting there is a bug associated with intersection between 1 point and 1 polygon, WHEN the point carries an attribute to be returned in the intersection process.

You might ask why do you actually need to have the attribute returned if there is just one point, this is because it is an iterative process in which it may not be just one point, it could be none or many.

I would appreciate somebody explaining this error or confirming my findings.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your example data in a more concise way.

```
library(raster)

pnt <- SpatialPoints(cbind(530124, 176950))
pol <- spPolygons(matrix(c(530106.8, 530127.5, 530127.5, 530106.8, 530106.8, 176953.3, 176953.3, 176933.3, 176933.3, 176953.3), ncol=2))
```

Now illustrate the problem.

```
intersect(pol, pnt)
#class       : SpatialPolygons 
#features    : 1 
#extent      : 530106.8, 530127.5, 176933.3, 176953.3  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : NA 

# this fails
intersect(pnt, pol)
#Loading required namespace: rgeos
#Error in j[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

# but it works with two points!
intersect(bind(pnt, pnt), pol)
#class       : SpatialPoints 
#features    : 2 
#extent      : 530124, 530124, 176950, 176950  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : NA
```

This was another `drop=TRUE` bug caused by the R default of "dropping" matrices to vectors when a single row is selected. This was fixed in raster version 2.6-11 (not on CRAN yet).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't answer your intersect bug question, but it might be simpler for now to use sp::over to return polygon attributes to points

```
# dummy polygon
xym <- as.matrix(data.frame(x=c(16.48438,17.49512,24.74609,22.59277,16.48438),
y=c(59.73633,55.12207,55.03418,61.14258,59.73633)))

# make into SpatialPolygon
p = Polygon(xym)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))

# Promote to SPDF and give an attribute
SPDF = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sps, data.frame(N = "hello", row.names = 1))

# make 2 points, one inside the polygon and one outside
p <- data.frame(x=c(16,18),y=c(58,58))
coordinates(p) <- ~x + y

# plot to check
plot(sps)
plot(p,add=T)

# perform the over, returns a named vector for every point in the SpatialPoints
res <- unname(over(p,SPDF))

# promote points to SpatialPointsDataFrame and put in new polygon attribute
data <- data.frame(ID=row.names(p),pol=res)
sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(p, data)
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually devised a work around for the bug, its pretty nasty in that it catches the error if it happens, and defines the point index which should come from the intersection function manually.  I'm sure somebody will find your comment useful though!